# Adding seat numbers to the images ajax, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm doing something like seats booking page and Seat numbers, A1, A2, ... G1, ... G17, G18 should be added to the image tag dynamically on page load and display as tooltips when the mouse hovers over them.

This is my function but it doesn't work:

```
function allocateSeats(){

var table = $("#seats");
var num = 0;
var rowName;    

table.each(function(){
    $(this).find('img').each(function(){
        var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
        var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
        num ++;

        switch(true){
        case(num<7):
            rowName='A';
        break;
        case(num>6 && num<13):
            rowName='B';
        break;
        case(num>12 && num<19):
            rowName='C';
        break;
        case(num>18 && num<37):
            rowName='D';
        break;
        case(num>36 && num<55):
            rowName='E';
        break;
        case(num>54 && num<73):
            rowName='F';
        break;
        case(num>72 && num<91):
            rowName='G';
        break;
        }
        //alert("Column: " + col + ", Row: " + row); -----This should work
        $(this).attr('id',rowName + row);
        $(this).attr('title',rowName + row);
        $(this).draggable({
            helper: 'clone',
            revert: 'invalid',
            cursor: 'move'
        });

        $("#topLeft").droppable({
            drop: handleDropEvent,
            out: handleDropOut
        });

    })
})

}
```

Comment: Protip: anything attribute related is already associated to the DOM object. `this.id` and `this.title` are much faster than the jQuery attr method.

Comment: @Sterling Archer could you exlain in more details

Comment: `this` is already offered. Using `$(this)` returns a jQuery object of the DOM object that is `this`. `$(this).attr("id",rowName + row)` is a much slower manipulation of `this.id = rowName + row`. For properties (id, title, href, src, etc) jQuery is overhead.

Comment: What doesn't work, do you get the alert's you're expecting? Can you make a JsFiddle/similar? Any JS errors?

Comment: @Sterling Archer ok, but still why my function doesn't work

Comment: @Dave Salomon it doesn't work becasue when i hover over the image nothing comes up, and if i click on the seat it doesn't show the id of seat, if I add id manualy the everything work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you don't add the seat row and column numbers and title attributes while creating the image elements( probably using php for loops ) ?

i guess somewhere in your server side code you could have something like this 
* pseudo code *

```
<?php 
$rowNames = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G');
for ($row = 0; $row < 10; $row+ ) { 
    /* get new letter for the new row that will begin with for loop */
    $rowName = array_shift($rowNames);

    echo '<tr data-rowname="row_'.$rowName.'">';
    for ($col= 0; $col< 10; $col+ ) {
        echo '<td ><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10" id="seat_"'.$row.'_'.$col.'></td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>"
}
?>
```

I'm assuming you dont have the seats html page saved as static html, and is most likely generated using nested for loops. And if thats the case, you can also create row , column numbers and letters while the page is being generated.

Edited with new solution.

JsFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/j2k0n5ra/5/

```
and code

<table id="seats">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

var table = $("#seats");
var rows  = $("tr");
var seats,seat;
var rowNr, seatNr;
var rowLabels = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"];
var rowLabel;
for (rowNr = 0; rowNr < rows.length; rowNr++) {
      var seats  = $(rows.get(rowNr)).find("td");
    rowLabel = rowLabels.shift();
   for (seatNr = 0; seatNr < seats.length; seatNr++) {
     seat = $(seats.get(seatNr)).find("img");
       seat.get(0).title = rowLabel + seatNr;
       seat.get(0).id = rowLabel + seatNr;
       seat.after("<div class='label'>"+rowLabel + seatNr+"</div>");
   }  
}

table tr td img {width: 48px; height: 48px;}
table tr td {position: relative;}
.label {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: hi, my page is static html I'm using jqery and ajax to make it dynamic

Comment: my task is to add titles dynamicly

Comment: probably im doing something wrong but could you tell me why this example not working outside fidle I created blank page and I pasted your code for testing and I failed to make it work, Any ideas? thank

Comment: the code in js fiddle uses JQuery, do you have it on your page ?

can you open a javascript console and see if there are any errors and paste them here.

Comment: Latest version, but it shouldnt really matter since i dont use any advanced features of jQuery.

ps , can you upload this "blank page" somewhere where i could see it.

Comment: thanks man it's working, however if in <td> tag is a leeter A or B or etc, then is not working and it must be like that as this is in my temlpate how to fix this, thanks for the solution !!!

Comment: Writing letters into table cells souldnt cause any problems.
e.g if you write
<td> A <img src="http://placehold.it/10x10"/></td>
it still has correct title and id.

Comment: @ Rainer Plumer but if you type just letters name of cell for example without image it will cuse problems, however I manage to go around and insted of letter A,B,C etc I added png of letters, I know its bad practie and I should do that proper way but hey it's working so why not, thanks again man without your help I couldn't achive that

Comment: Well, having letters as pngs isnt really that bad idea if you dont plan on changing them later on ( changing font or background would require remaking all the letters )

you can also try this fiddle. I made a small modification to allow letters as seats
 http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/50kyo3cx/2/